# Can you let computer play your character when you are away from the keyboard?

Tags: warhammer-vermintide

Is it possible to let the computer play your character in Warhammer: Vermintide like it was in L4D. I remember in L4D you could give control of your character to computer when you were going away. is there such an option in Vermintide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are unable to do that in Vermintide. Instead of turning into a bot, you will literally just stand there and be hit by the hordes that come every now and then.